# 'rake device' keeps on crashing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xcode, ios-simulator, rubymotion

I have created an app with Ruby Motion which opens in the simulator. But it crashes when I try to open it with the device.

I have registered the device and have created an IOP Provisionning Profile which I have included in the app's Rake file as well as in a folder 'signing' in the main menu of the app.

And this is the terminal's info about the reason for crashing.
I'd appreciate help very much as I have tried everything I could think of.

Thanks
Daniel

```
Build ./build/iPhoneOS-9.3-Development
     Build /Users/danielo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/motion-yaml-1.4/lib/YAMLKit
     Build /Users/danielo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/cdq-1.0.8/lib/../vendor/cdq/ext
      Link ./build/iPhoneOS-9.3-Development/4capisco.app/4capisco
    Create ./build/iPhoneOS-9.3-Development/4capisco.app/Info.plist
    Create ./build/iPhoneOS-9.3-Development/4capisco.app/embedded.mobileprovision
  Codesign ./build/iPhoneOS-9.3-Development/4capisco.app
    Create ./build/iPhoneOS-9.3-Development/4capisco.ipa
    Deploy ./build/iPhoneOS-9.3-Development/4capisco.ipa
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
/Library/RubyMotion/lib/motion/project/template/ios/config.rb:210:in `read_provisioned_profile_array'
/Library/RubyMotion/lib/motion/project/template/ios/config.rb:233:in `provisioned_devices'
/Library/RubyMotion/lib/motion/project/template/ios.rb:273:in `block in <top (required)>'
/Users/danielo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/danielo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => device
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
Daniel-Os-MacBook-Pro:4capisco danielo$
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been resolved.
The mobileprovision file die not have a "ProvisionalDevices", so I downloaded it again.
And it worked right away.